# MemoryStream replacement?

Tags: c#, .net, memorystream

A few weeks ago I read something about a new class in .Net 4/4.5 that performs better than [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx), but I can't seem to find it anymore.

I've looked in the [IO namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx) and could not find anything. Does anyone remember reading something like that?

Thanks

Comment: I was actually talking about Memory-Mapped Files:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx

Comment: Hard for anyone to guess that :-)  Memory mapped files have been around for a long time.  They're just conveniently wrapped by the .NET runtime in .NET 4.

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps you read about Memory Tributary, a CodePlex project that provides a MemoryStream replacement better suited for large amounts of memory

> MemoryTributary is a MemoryStream replacement using multiple memory segments to store the content of the stream, as opposed to the single byte array of MemoryStream. It is designed to be a complete replacement, capable of handling the large datasets that MemoryStream cannot.

http://memorytributary.codeplex.com/

Comment: Yes I found that one too, but I think it was something else, let me see what other people say. Thanks

Comment: I went over the framework changes for 4 and 4.5 pretty carefully and don't recall anything like that.  Still, would be pleasantly surprised if someone else found something new.

Comment: OK fair enough, it seems that I must have confused that with something else. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Not the answer that OP was looking for, but it may be usefull for someone like me who searches for MemoryStream replacement:
[RecyclableMemoryStream released by Bing team](http://www.philosophicalgeek.com/2015/02/06/announcing-microsoft-io-recycablememorystream/), which is actually better performing `MemoryStream` drop-in replacement.