# How to solve memory issues when doing lots of serialization with memory streams

Tags: .net, .net-core, json.net

I have a monthly data archiving webjob running on Azure that pulls a month's worth of data for about 5000 remote devices that are regularly posting data into Azure tables.  The basic approach after the data is retrieved is to serialize it into a Memory Stream, then GZIP compress this stream into another stream and then upload the resulting stream to Azure Datalake blob storage.  Here is the code currently being used:

```
public static async Task<String> ArchiveDataAsync(String container, String path, String filenameWithoutExtension, Object data)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Attempting to serialize, compress and upload data to data lake...");
            using (var uncompressedMs = new MemoryStream())
            using (var compressedMs = new MemoryStream())
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(uncompressedMs))
            {
                // Serialize data
                Console.WriteLine("Starting serialization...");
                var serializer = new JsonSerializer
                {
                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                    Formatting = Formatting.None
                };
                serializer.Serialize(streamWriter, data);
                uncompressedMs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                Console.WriteLine("Serialization completed successfully.");

                Console.WriteLine("Starting data compression...");
                using (var compressionStream = new GZipStream(compressedMs, CompressionMode.Compress))
                {
                    // Compress data
                    await uncompressedMs.CopyToAsync(compressionStream);
                    await compressionStream.FlushAsync();
                    compressedMs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Data compression successfully completed.  Compression rate achieved: {Math.Round(100 - (100.0 * compressedMs.Length / uncompressedMs.Length), 1)}%.");

                    // Save data to Data Lake
                    Console.WriteLine($"Starting data upload to {path + "/" + filenameWithoutExtension}.json.gz...");
                    var dataLakeServiceClient = InSysDataLake.BlobStorage.GetDataLakeServiceClient();
                    var dataLakeFileSystemClient = InSysDataLake.BlobStorage.GetFileSystemClient(dataLakeServiceClient, container);
                    await InSysDataLake.BlobStorage.UploadFileFromMemoryStreamAsync(dataLakeFileSystemClient, path, filenameWithoutExtension + ".json.gz", compressedMs);
                    Console.WriteLine("Data upload completed successfully.");
                    return "OK";
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.TraceError(Helper.GenerateErrorMessage("InSysDataProcessing.DataArchiving.ArchiveDataAsync", ex));
            return $"ERROR: {ex.StackTrace}";
        }
    }
```

The UploadFileFromMemoryStream method is:

```
public static async Task UploadFileFromMemoryStreamAsync(DataLakeFileSystemClient fileSystemClient, String directoryName, String filename, MemoryStream contentMS)
        {

            DataLakeDirectoryClient directoryClient = fileSystemClient.GetDirectoryClient(directoryName);
            DataLakeFileClient fileClient = await directoryClient.CreateFileAsync(filename).ConfigureAwait(false);

            contentMS.Position = 0;
            var contentSize = contentMS.Length;
            await fileClient.AppendAsync(contentMS, offset: 0).ConfigureAwait(false);
            await fileClient.FlushAsync(position: contentSize).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

The compressed streams end up around 5-20MB, and the uncompressed serialized data can be 5-10 times bigger (as big as 250Mb).  The process using this archiving method is calling this to store the monthly data for each device, and then it aggregates all the data for the devices at a particular location and archives that.  It is getting called 5-10000 times over the space of 5-10 hours.

Every now and then (but frequently enough to be a problem) I see the following error:

```
[07/30/2020 16:43:07 > 2ef8ea: INFO] Monthly location data for ... for 3/2019 FAILED to be archived: ERROR:    at System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
[07/30/2020 16:43:07 > 2ef8ea: INFO]    at System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity(Int32 value)
[07/30/2020 16:43:07 > 2ef8ea: INFO]    at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
[07/30/2020 16:43:07 > 2ef8ea: INFO]    at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
[07/30/2020 16:43:07 > 2ef8ea: INFO]    at System.IO.StreamWriter.Write(Char value)
[07/30/2020 16:43:07 > 2ef8ea: INFO]    at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter.WriteValueDelimiter()
[07/30/2020 16:43:07 > 2ef8ea: INFO]    at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.AutoComplete(JsonToken tokenBeingWritten)
[07/30/2020 16:43:07 > 2ef8ea: INFO]    at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter.WritePropertyName(String name, Boolean escape)
[07/30/2020 16:43:07 > 2ef8ea: INFO]    at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
[07/30/2020 16:43:07 > 2ef8ea: INFO]    at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
[07/30/2020 16:43:07 > 2ef8ea: INFO]    at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
[07/30/2020 16:43:07 > 2ef8ea: INFO]    at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
[07/30/2020 16:43:07 > 2ef8ea: INFO]    at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
[07/30/2020 16:43:07 > 2ef8ea: INFO]    at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
[07/30/2020 16:43:07 > 2ef8ea: INFO]    at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
[07/30/2020 16:43:07 > 2ef8ea: INFO]    at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
[07/30/2020 16:43:07 > 2ef8ea: INFO]    at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
[07/30/2020 16:43:07 > 2ef8ea: INFO]    at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
[07/30/2020 16:43:07 > 2ef8ea: INFO]    at InSysDataProcessing.DataArchiving.ArchiveDataAsync(String container, String path, String filenameWithoutExtension, Object data) in E:\InergySystems\GitHub\InSysCore\InSysDataManagement\DataArchiving.cs:line 60.
```

This only happens for the aggregated location data, i.e., for the larger data sets.  It looks like after a while the memory is getting too fragmented.  In the process that calls the archiving function I added:

```
GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce;
GC.Collect();
```

after each call to the archiver, but this has not helped.  I've also tried scaling up the App Service Plan on which the webjob is running (currently a P3v2, 16 GB RAM, but this performed no better than the plan with 7GB RAM).

At this point I'm not sure what to try next.

Comment: You can compress as you serialize.  The compression will be nearly as good as long as you use a large enough buffer.  That completely eliminates the memory required by `uncompressedMs`.  See: [Can I decompress and deserialize a file using streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32943899/3744182).

Comment: Also see [MemoryStream replacement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12713886/3744182), https://github.com/Microsoft/Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream and [alternative to MemoryStream for large data volumes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17921880/3744182).  In fact maybe the questions I've linked answer yours also?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I decompress and deserialize a file using streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32943899/can-i-decompress-and-deserialize-a-file-using-streams)

Comment: Many thanks for all the links above - seems like I was not utilizing the streams in the best way.  I have made revisions and the resulting code is far simpler and more robust - I'm not seeing any memory issues now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the links provided in the comments to the question above, I revised the code and it is now much simpler and more robust.  Here is the amending method that is in use now with no memory errors, even for >450MB of uncompressed serialized data:

```
const int BufferSize = 16384;

public static async Task<String> ArchiveDataAsync(String container, String path, String filenameWithoutExtension, Object data)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Attempting to serialize, compress and upload data to data lake...");

                try
                {
                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (var gzip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
                        {
                            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(gzip, Encoding.UTF8, BufferSize))
                            {
                                var serializer = new JsonSerializer
                                {
                                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                                    Formatting = Formatting.None
                                };
                                serializer.Serialize(writer, data);
                            }
                        }

                        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                        // Save data to Data Lake
                        Console.WriteLine($"Starting data upload to {path + "/" + filenameWithoutExtension}.json.gz...");
                        var dataLakeServiceClient = BlobStorage.GetDataLakeServiceClient();
                        var dataLakeFileSystemClient = BlobStorage.GetFileSystemClient(dataLakeServiceClient, container);
                        await BlobStorage.UploadFileFromMemoryStreamAsync(dataLakeFileSystemClient, path, filenameWithoutExtension + ".json.gz", ms);
                        Console.WriteLine("Data upload completed successfully.");
                        return "OK";
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Trace.TraceError(Helper.GenerateErrorMessage("InSysDataProcessing.DataArchiving.Json.ArchiveDataAsync", ex));
                    return $"ERROR: {ex.StackTrace}";
                }
            }
```